# Make zero appear last in a sorted list of integers

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a list of objects and want to order them by some property

```
List<Foo> foo = GetList();    
return foo.OrderBy(foo => foo.DisplayOrder);
```

The catch is that when `DisplayOrder` is zero I need to place that item in *last* position.

My question is the same as [make zero appear last in a list of ascending numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232537/make-zero-appear-last-in-a-list-of-ascending-numbers) but in C#. It's easy to solve but I want to see some creative, concise answers.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the fact that you can order by a boolean value. If you first order by `DisplayOrder == 0` this will results to `true` for all zero values and `false` for all other values. Since `true` will ordered after `false` all zero values will be at the very end:

```
return foo.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder == 0)
          .ThenBy(x => x.DisplayOrder);
```

Comment: Is that not backwards? Finally ordering by `DisplayOrder` will just put 0 back at the top, won't it?

Comment: @djacobson: No - `0 == 0` will evaluate to `true` which will come after all `false` values - at the very end

Comment: @djacobson No, a 'false' becomes before a 'true'.

Comment: +1 Right. I misunderstood how `ThenBy` is applied. I retract my comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
return foo.OrderBy(foo => foo.DisplayOrder == 0 ? int32.MaxValue : foo.DisplayOrder);
```